# Installing Anaconda screwed up virtualenvs

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, anaconda

I have been using virtual envs with pip with much success (https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito) for the last couple years. Today I thought I would give anaconda a try. I installed it, per the command line instructions. After tinkering for a moment, I thought I better get back to work. I opened up a new terminal window and did my usual `workon my_project` and guess what I found?

`-bash: workon: command not found`

Well that's not very encouraging. Anyone have any ideas on how to have these both installed successfully? Or at least how to get rid of anaconda and get my virtualenvs back?

Comment: uninstall anaconda by removing the directory where it's installed (e.g., `~/anaconda3`)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so the biggest issue that anaconda created for me is that they changed my default python. This is what was screwing up virtualenv burrito. After uninstalling anaconda (I don't know if I needed to do that or not), I had to go into the .bashrc file and remove the line that changed my default python, I don't remember exactly what it looked like, but it was pretty obvious and they had a comment above it saying that anaconda put it there. Once I did that and uninstalled/reinstalled virtualenv burrito and remade all my virtualenvs I was back in business.